# Yocto project: -boot-stm32mp-v2021.10-stm32mp-r2-r0 do_compile: oe_runmake failed

Tags: stm32, yocto

currently I am learning yocto project. I tried the basic yocto image with beaglebone black and poky distribution and it worked perfectly. Right now I am trying the same proecess for stm32mp1. I am following a tutorial from digikey [tuorial link](https://www.digikey.com/en/maker/projects/intro-to-embedded-linux-part-2-yocto-project/2c08a1ad09d74f20b9844e566d332da4). I am getting u-boot-stm32mp error. The error is following:

```
ERROR: u-boot-stm32mp-v2021.10-stm32mp-r2-r0 do_compile: oe_runmake failed
ERROR: u-boot-stm32mp-v2021.10-stm32mp-r2-r0 do_compile: ExecutionError('/home/hico/argon-stm32/build_argon/tmp/work/stm32mp1-poky-linux-gnueabi/u-boot-stm32mp/v2021.10-stm32mp-r2-r0/temp/run.do_compile.1968416', 1, None, None)
ERROR: Logfile of failure stored in: /home/hico/argon-stm32/build_argon/tmp/work/stm32mp1-poky-linux-gnueabi/u-boot-stm32mp/v2021.10-stm32mp-r2-r0/temp/log.do_compile.1968416
```

I have following configuration for the setup:

```
BB_VERSION           = "2.0.0"
BUILD_SYS            = "x86_64-linux"
NATIVELSBSTRING      = "universal"
TARGET_SYS           = "arm-poky-linux-gnueabi"
MACHINE              = "stm32mp1"
DISTRO               = "poky"
DISTRO_VERSION       = "4.0.10"
TUNE_FEATURES        = "arm vfp cortexa7 neon vfpv4 thumb callconvention-hard"
TARGET_FPU           = "hard"
meta                 
meta-poky            
meta-yocto-bsp       = "kirkstone:43b94d2b8496eae6e512c6deb291b5908b7ada47"
meta-oe              
meta-python          = "kirkstone:bdad2a789e30703a825b876279665720d06d55dc"
meta-st-stm32mp      = "kirkstone:ca501bd7dbe023682903ceedddaacd940b0898f4"
```

I am using ubuntu 22.04.01 and virtual machine 5.19.04.1

Does anyone have any idea about the error. Any kind of help is highly appreciable.

I tried the 'bitbake -c cleanall u-boot-stm32mp' and rebuild the image again, but still got the same error.
I am expecting a clean build, where I won't have any u-boot-stm32mp oe runmake error.

I got this error from the log file.

| Please add these via Kconfig instead. Find a suitable Kconfig
| file and add a 'config' or 'menuconfig' option.
| make[1](https://pastebin.com/kJbWZ1V6): *** [/home/hico/work/argon_test/yocto/build-argon/tmp/work-shared/stm32mp1/uboot-source/Makefile:1107: .binman_stamp] Error 1
| make[1](https://pastebin.com/kJbWZ1V6): *** Deleting file '.binman_stamp'
| make[1](https://pastebin.com/kJbWZ1V6): *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
| make[1](https://pastebin.com/kJbWZ1V6): Leaving directory '/home/hico/work/argon_test/yocto/build-argon/tmp/work/stm32mp1-poky-linux-gnueabi/u-boot-stm32mp/v2021.10-stm32mp-r2-r0/build/stm32mp15_defconfig'
| make: Leaving directory '/home/hico/work/argon_test/yocto/build-argon/tmp/work-shared/stm32mp1/uboot-source'
| make: *** [Makefile:177: sub-make] Error 2
| ERROR: oe_runmake failed
| WARNING: exit code 1 from a shell command.

In the following link you can find the whole log file.

[log file for oe make error](https://pastebin.com/kJbWZ1V6)

Comment: What's the error you get? Somewhere above in the log there is the actual reason for the failure, that supposed to be more helpful.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. At the end of the post I add the error from the log file.

Comment: Have you set `UBOOT_MACHINE` variable somewhere in local.conf, or some other suitable place? (Also, maybe a bit more of the top of that error could be useful. What config/options is it complaining about?)

Comment: Looking at st's repo, `UBOOT_MACHINE` is configured through `UBOOT_CONFIG`, so it doesn't have to be set, forget that part. Seeing more of the error would be better.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/kJbWZ1V6

Thanks for your reply. in the above link you can find the whole log file.

Comment: That `CONFIG_FS_EXT4` option doesn't seem to be part of neither `meta-st-stm32mp` nor of `u-boot` source. Have you added it somewhere?

Comment: No I have not aadded it, I just add Machine as stm32mp1 in local.conf and added two layer for meta-st-stm32mp and meta-openembedded/meta-python and meta-openembedded/meta-oe layer in bblayers.conf

Comment: I would like to add 1 thing that if I choose machine as Beaglebone black then it's working fine, problem occurs when I choose machine as stm321mp1. I also tried the machine as stm32mp1_disco, but got the same error.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your generous support. Later I installed a new virtual machine and did all the process again and this time it worked. I was able to build the yocto image in kirkstone version without any error.

Comment: Hmmm... interesting. Thanks for the update. Maybe there was some code contamination building the package for different machines...

Comment: Right now I am trying to flashing the image on SDcard, I am following the FLASHLayout_sdcard_stm32mp15a-dk1-trusted.tsv file for the partition instruction. Also took help from the digikez tutorial. But I am gettinng error like 'unable to find the partition with the uuid mentioned in metadata'. Do zou have any idea for this error. Thanks.